# Data mining forum

Tags: data-mining

Hi all,

shouldn't there be a "Data mining" subforum on stackexchange?

Answer (score 4):

See Area51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/

My opinion is that it should be covered here.

Comment: I agree. Too many SE sites are bad, because than the effective probability that the question will collide with someone that knows the answer decreases.

Comment: The scope of this site includes "data mining" and "machine learning". See the faq.

Comment: @Rob: The FAQ does not specify "machine learning"; should we add it?

Comment: It's in the proposed FAQ at http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-should-our-faq-contain
Do you know when/how we can add the material there to http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq?

Comment: classical statistics, machine learning, and data mining should all be on the same site

Answer (score 1):

I don't think stackexchange sites are meant to be forums?

My knowledge of "Data mining" is a bit limited, but what sort of questions would people ask that wouldn't be covered in the remit of this stackexchange?